# Parametric Plot 3D: A curve and a surface plot together

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions, differential-geometry

I am **new** to Mathematica and
I tried to make a superimposed plot of a curve on a half sphere and need help with some graphics.

This is the code line that i used to generate the following graphs

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{1 + Cos[t], Sin[t],2*Sin[t/2]}, {2 *Cos[t]*Sin[\[Phi]], 2*Sin[t]*Sin[\[Phi]],2*Cos[\[Phi]]}}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},{\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2},PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thickness[0.025]], Yellow},PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Curve 1", "Sphere"},BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, Axes -> False, Background -> Gray,Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 10]
```

I obtained the following output

[image]

and with little change in the background this one

[image]

**Question**:

I want to know if the visual of the general curve can be improved
and if one could **put arrowheads along the *Curve 1* in the anti-clockwise sense of rotation**. What could be the procedure?

When I turn off the Mesh, the *Curve 1* also vanishes. How could I keep the curve and put *Mesh-> None* on the surface at the same time?

Comment: It might be better if you plot your space curve and sphere in separate `ParametricPlot3D[]` calls, and then combine them with `Show[]`. You will of course have to manually add a legend with `Legended[]` afterwards if you do this.

Comment: Thanks J.M. So, I should plot c1 and s1 and the two curves and then use Show[c1,s1], right? Then use Legended in the Show[c1,s1] command?

Comment: something like it, yes

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did and have the desired output. Still not sure how to label my curve $\alpha(t)$. I shall try it and find out over the StackExchange.

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question showing what you've already done, and then I (or someone else) could offer tips.

Answer (score 4):

This is what i have been able to do so far.

[[image: The curve <span class=]$\alpha(t)$ over the surface of the upper-half $\mathcal{S}^2$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4EiB.jpg)

and here is the code

```
Clear[c1, s1]
c1 = ParametricPlot3D[{1 + Cos[t], Sin[t], 2*Sin[t/2]}, {t, 0, 
 2 \[Pi]}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.005]], 
  Arrowheads[{0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True] /. Line -> Arrow;

s1 = ParametricPlot3D[{2 *Cos[t]*Sin[\[Phi]], 2*Sin[t]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
2*Cos[\[Phi]]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow,Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 10]], PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, Axes -> False, Background -> White, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> None];
Show[{c1, s1}]
```

Comment: At this point, you could just do something like `Legended[Show[{c1, s1}], SwatchLegend[{Red, Yellow}, {"Curve 1", "Sphere"}]]` if you want to add the legend.

Comment: Sure! shall try it out. Thank you for your time.